# My for loop and while loop stops at specific number

Tags: python, for-loop

I would like to write a program that excludes every string from a list.

```
lst =  ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
for i in lst:
 if isinstance(i, str):
   lst.remove(i)
print(lst)
```

I would like to know why the result of the above code is`['e', 'o']`.

Comment: When you remove the first element of the list (`a`), the second element of the list becomes `i`, which you remove and then the third element of the list is `u`, which you remove, leaving you with `['e', 'o']`

Answer (score 4):

```
for i in lst.copy():
```

Iterate over a copy of the data if you want to change it.

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification, this works as expected.
Basically `lst[:]` creates a slice of the original list that contains all elements. For more information on the slice notation, see this wonderful answer in [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

```
lst =  ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
for i in lst[:]:
 if isinstance(i, str):
   lst.remove(i)
print(lst)
```

When run this outputs an empty list:

```
[]
```